# Difference between find_elements_by_<attribute> and WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have recently started working on selenium-python. Both of these give same output. I want to know if there is any difference

```
time.sleep(10)
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(<some-xpath>).get_attribute('textContent')
```

and

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, <some-xpath>))).get_attribute('textContent')
```

Answer (score 2):

With your first code

```
time.sleep(10)
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(<some-xpath>).get_attribute('textContent')
```

your script will wait for 10 seconds and then return the element that's matching with the xpath. However, when you use the second code

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, <some-xpath>))).get_attribute('textContent')
```

the element will be returned as and when it's available. Script will keep checking for the element at a max of 10 seconds.

So, always better to use the <kbd>ExplicitWait</kbd> as shown in the second part of your code.

Consider that the element is displayed with in 3 seconds, then you are wasting `7` seconds in the first approach, but with second approach the script will move-on to the next step right after the element is present on the 3rd second (saving `7` seconds of execution time for one element, think about this in the larger scale).

Comment: If you feel this issue is resolved, please accept the answer for the benefit of future visitors.